# PineScript-Draw Box

Tags: pine-script

I don't have any experience with Pine Script.
My question is, is it possible to draw a box under a current bar, with possibility to define the height in ticks, and the price for the top or bottom of it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create boxes I pine script and define height, width, location, color and more.
[image: pine script boxes]

Here is the script:

```
//@version=5
indicator("", "", true)
box.new(bar_index, high, bar_index + 1, low, border_color = color.gray, bgcolor = color.new(color.silver, 60))
```

Here you can find the manual. Scroll down on the page to boxes. [box and lines manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Lines_and_boxes.html?highlight=box#boxes)

Comment: Thank you very much Marcus.